# Compare rows from the Sqlserver table with the indexes generated in the Array

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server

I have a single TBResult table in Sql Server 2014, with 2,500 saved Results per Contest Number, following format:
[image]

```
private Label[] LabelResult = new Label[15]; // dynamically created
```

[image]

I need to compare each new draw generated in the [LabelResult] array with the database records and know the number of hits I would have with 11 numbers, how many hits with 12 numbers, how many hits with 13 numbers, how many hits with 14 numbers and how many hits there would be with 15 numbers.

like a lottery where you choose 15 numbers from 01 to 25 and win the prize according to the number of numbers you hit.

OBSERVATION: the Numbers entered in the array will not be saved in the Database, I only need the comparison with the Results Table.

I need it to appear like this in the EX Labels:

```
Summary:

You would have scored 11 hits in 250 contests.
You would have scored 12 hits in 55 contests.
You would have scored 13 hits in 6 contests.
You would have made 14 hits in 1 contest.
You wouldn't have done 15 hits.
```

try this way but got no results

```
private int NewCount()
    {   
        ContestResult c = new ContestResult();
        int response= 0;
        DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDaConexao);
        cx.Open();
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

        query.AppendLine("SELECT _01, _02, _03, _04, _05, _06, _07, _08, _09, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15 form TBResult," );
        query.AppendLine("SELECT value FROM " + LabelResult [0].Text + LabelResult [3].Text + LabelResult [2].Text + LabelResult [4].Text + LabelResult [4].Text +
            LabelResult [5].Text + LabelResult [6].Text + LabelResult [7].Text + LabelResult [8].Text + LabelResult [9].Text +
            LabelResult [10].Text + LabelResult [11].Text + LabelResult [12].Text + LabelResult [13].Text + LabelResult [14].Text  );
        query.AppendLine(" WITH T AS( SELECT *, MatchCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(SELECT * FROM(VALUES[_01],[_02], [_03], [_04], [_05],[_06], [_07], [_08], [_09], [_10],[_11], [_12], [_13], [_14], [_15]");
        query.AppendLine(")V(V)) T) FROM TBResult) SELECT *, RunningTotalForMatchCount = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MatchCount ORDER BY Contest) FROM T ORDER BY Contest");
    
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), cx.ObjetConexao);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        response= = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection = cx.ObjetConexao;
        return response; 
    }
```

my Class Generate randoms in order and not repeated.

```
 private void ShowArray()
    {
        int[] OrganizedNumbers = new int[15];

        Array.Sort(OrganizedNumbers);

        for (int i = 0; y < 15; i++)
        {
            LabelResult[i].Text = OrganizedNumbers[i].ToString("D2");
        }
    }
  private void Generator()
    {
        RandomClass rnd = new RandomClass();

        int[] luckyNumbers = rnd.non-repeatingGenerator(15, 1, 25);

        Array.Sort(luckyNumbers );

        Control[] controls = LabelResult 

        for (int i = 0; i < controls.Length; i++)
        {
            int value = (luckyNumbers [i];
            controls[i].Text = value.ToString("D2");
        }

    }`
```

my button would be like this

```
private void btnGenerateArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
  ShowArray();
//int operationsPerformed = NewCount();
        //if operationsPerformed == 11)
        //{
        //    lblResult11.Text = operationsPerformed.ToString();               
        //}
        //else if operationsPerformed == 12)
        //{
        //    lblResult12.Text = operationsPerformed.ToString();
        //}
        //else if operationsPerformed == 13)
        //{
        //    lblResult13.Text = operationsPerformed.ToString();
        //}
        //else if operationsPerformed == 14)
        //{
        //    lblResult14.Text = operationsPerformed.ToString();
        //}
        //else if operationsPerformed == 15)
        //{
        //    lblResult15.Text = operationsPerformed.ToString();
        //}
}
```

My model is like this:

```
public  class ContestResult
{
    public ContestResult()
    {
        this.Contest = 0;
        this._01 = 0;
        this._02 = 0;
        this._03 = 0;
        ...
        this._14 = 0;
        this._15 = 0;

    }
    public ContestResult(int Contest, int _01, int _02, int _03, int _04, int _05, int _06, int _07,
        int _08, int _09, int _10, int _11, int _12, int _13, int _14, int _15)
    {

        this.Contest = contest;
        this._01 = _01;
        this._02 = _02;
        this._03 = _03;
       ...
        this._14 = _14;
        this._15 = _15;
    }
    private int contest;
    public int Contest
    {
        get { return this.contest; }
        set { this.contest = value; }
    }
    private int _01;
    public int n_01
    {
        get { return this._01; }
        set { this._01 = value; }
    }
    private int _02;
    public int n_02
    {
        get { return this._02; }
        set { this._02 = value; }
    }
    private int _03;
    public int n_03
    {
        get { return this._03; }
        set { this._03 = value; }
    }
    ...
    private int _14;
    public int n_14
    {
        get { return this._14; }
        set { this._14 = value; }
    }
    private int _15;
    public int n_15
    {
        get { return this._15; }
        set { this._15 = value; }
    }
}
```

I'm new to this topic and I want to learn; I researched a lot and I didn't find something that answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another solution is to benefit from the [SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8) to read the rows from the db table one by one and do the math.

In a method, create a new array of objects and fix its size to equal the [`SqlDataReader.FieldCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.FieldCount)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) value. Pass the array to the [`SqlDataReader.GetValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValues)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) method to fill it with the values of the selected table fields. Then, compare them with the values taken from the `LabelResult` labels to count the equal values and keep the rows count for each result within the target range 11-15.

For example...

```cs
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int outVal;

    if (LabelResult.Any(lbl => !int.TryParse(lbl.Text, out outVal)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid values...");
        return;
    }

    var arr = LabelResult.Select(lbl => int.Parse(lbl.Text));
    var result = GetResult(arr);

    foreach (var kvp in result)
        Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key:D2}: {kvp.Value}");
}

private IDictionary<int, int> GetResult(IEnumerable<int> src)
{
    var dict = Enumerable.Range(11, 5).ToDictionary(k => k, v => 0);

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT _01, _02, _03, _04, _05, _06, _07, " +
            "_08, _09, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15 FROM TBResult";

        con.Open();

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                object[] arr = new object[rdr.FieldCount];
                rdr.GetValues(arr);
                IEnumerable<int> values = arr.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
                int matchCount = values.Intersect(src).Count();
                if (dict.ContainsKey(matches)) dict[matches]++;
            }
        }
    }

    return dict;
}
```

---

In case you have the same database values saved in a text file like:

```
03 04 05 06 08 09 10 11 12 14 16 18 19 20 22 
01 04 06 07 08 09 10 12 14 17 18 20 22 23 24 
01 02 03 05 07 09 10 12 15 18 19 20 22 24 25
```

Then, you can use it instead to generate the result dictionary. Read each line that represents a row, split the line by the used delimiter, select the items and convert them to `Integer` values to compare them with the given sequence of the same type.

For example...

```cs
private IDictionary<int, int> GetResultFromTextFile(IEnumerable<int> src)
{
    var filePath = @"Results.txt";
    var delimiter = new[] { ' ' };
    var dict = File.ReadLines(filePath)
        .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        .Aggregate(new Dictionary<int, int>(), (d, line) =>
        {
            var values = line
            .Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x => int.Parse(x));
            int matchCount = values.Intersect(src).Count();

            if (matchCount >= 11)
            {
                if (d.ContainsKey(matchCount))
                    d[matchCount]++;
                else
                    d[matchCount] = 1;
            }
            return d;
        });

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: hello @dr.null, Thank you very much, you are the man, it was perfect, just comment on the foreach and plumm, everything worked perfect, a hug from Geande and may God bless you always.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is missing some details but from what I can infer you need something along the following lines ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vs8OcnsI)).

I've used a JSON array to hold the "My Array" values but you can get them into a temp table/table variable/table expression any way you wish!

```
DECLARE @MyArray TABLE (Element VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT @MyArray
SELECT value
FROM OPENJSON ('["01", "02", "03", "05", "07", "09", "10", "12", "15", "18", "19", "20", "22", "24", "25"]');



WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       MatchCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM (VALUES(_01), (_02), (_03), (_04), (_05),
                                                                (_06), (_07), (_08), (_09), (_10),
                                                                (_11), (_12), (_13), (_14), (_15)      
       )V(V) INTERSECT SELECT Element FROM @MyArray) T)
FROM [dbo].Result
)
SELECT *, 
       RunningTotalForMatchCount = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MatchCount ORDER BY Contents)  
FROM T
ORDER BY Contents
```

Comment: Martin Smith, Thank you very much for your answer, I understand that the question was missing some details, I realized that the version of SQL Server was missing, which is V.2014 and is not compatible with OPENJSON, I apologize for my ignorance, regarding your answer, this is exactly what I need, I am studying a way to get the Total results by a temporary Table, thank you very much.

Comment: @EdilsonLemos - The `OPRNJSON` is only used very tangentially. You just need to insert 15 rows into the table any how. This could just be 15 parameters `INSERT @MyArray VALUES (@Param1),(@Param2),(@Param3),(@Param4)...`

Comment: Colleague, apologies for my stupidity, as you said, my question lacks details, I really analyzed everything and realized my mistake, My Array will not be saved in the Database, it only generates the numbers that go to a DataGridV and then it is printed on paper, the results are already there in the database, I only need to compare with the results that are already in the Database, and get how many rows from the database I would have hits with 11, 12, 13, 14 and 15 numbers s. myArray would be like a lottery, play 15 random numbers and compare how many you got right, your help was very useful,

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it via SQL Server's XML and XQuery.

The solution is completely dynamic, It will work regardless of how many columns in the @Result table.

Notable points:

- $p variable contains a sequence of the @Result table values for each
  row.
- $q variable contains a sequence of the @inputArray values.
- A simple `count($p[.=$q])` counts a value-based intersection between $p and $q sequences.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @Result TABLE (
Contents [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_01] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_02] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_03] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_04] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_05] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_06] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_07] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_08] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_09] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_10] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_11] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_12] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_13] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_14] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_15] [varchar](5) NOT NULL
);
INSERT @Result VALUES 
('Row1', '01','02','03','04','05','07','09','12','15','18','20','22','23','24','25'),
('Row2', '01','02','03','04','05','08','09','12','13','14','15','16','18','20','21'),
('Row3', '01','02','03','04','05','09','11','12','13','14','17','21','22','24','25');

DECLARE @MyArray2 TABLE (r VARCHAR(5));
INSERT @MyArray2 VALUES
('01'), ('02'), ('03'), ('05'), ('07'), ('09'), ('10'), ('12'), ('15'), ('18'), ('19'), ('20'), ('22'), ('24'), ('25');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @inputArray XML = (SELECT * 
FROM @MyArray2
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('array'));

-- a value-based intersection via XQuery
SELECT t.* 
    , c.query('
        let $p := /root/*[contains(local-name(),"_")]/text()
        let $q := /root/array/r/text()
        return count($p[.=$q])
    ').value('.','INT') AS MatchCount 
FROM @Result AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.*, @inputArray FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| Contents | _01 | _02 | _03 | _04 | _05 | _06 | _07 | _08 | _09 | _10 | _11 | _12 | _13 | _14 | _15 | MatchCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row1 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 07 | 09 | 12 | 15 | 18 | 20 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 13 |
| Row2 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 08 | 09 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 18 | 20 | 21 | 9 |
| Row3 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 09 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 17 | 21 | 22 | 24 | 25 | 9 |

**c#**

Here is how to compose daily XML on the client. The idea is to pass it as a parameter to SQL Server.

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<array/>");
    // add all needed elements in a loop
    xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("r", "01"));
    xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("r", "02"));
    Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
}
```

Comment: ola Yitzhak Khabinsky, Thank you very much for the answer, the problem is that I don't know how to get the data from the Label Array which is an array that has a different result every day, get and throw this data in place of @MyArray2, so that it can be compared with the results that are already in the table.

Comment: That's correct. You need to truncate and populate that @MyArray2 table with your daily data.  Or even easier way. Just compose XML on the client, and assign its value to the  `@inputArray` T-SQL variable.

Comment: Its format as follows: `<array><r>01</r><r>02</r><r>03</r><r>05</r><r>07</r><r>09</r><r>10</r><r>12</r><r>15</r><r>18</r><r>19</r><r>20</r><r>22</r><r>24</r><r>25</r></array>`

Comment: I updated the answer with the daily XML composition on a client in c#.

Comment: Colleague, apologies for my stupidity, I will create a new question with more details, I really appreciate your answer, it was very useful, a big hug.